# Inverted search from set with Redis

Tags: search, tags, redis, set

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I'm trying to create a blog using Express and Redis.

My problem is that I'm kind of lost in NoSQL and I can't really see how I should design my Redis data.

I wanted to do :

```
SET global:postsNb 0
SET posts:1:text blablabla
SADD posts:1:tags a
SADD posts:1:tags b
SADD posts:1:tags c
```

It seems quite natural but I don't know how I can search **all posts where a in tags**.

Could you help me pls ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems quite natural but I don't know how I can search all posts where a in tags.

You will need somthing like:

```
SADD tags:[tagname] [postId]
```

e.g, when creating a post (with id=1, tags=a,b,c, content=...) run the following commands:

```
SADD tags:a 1
SADD tags:b 1
SADD tags:c 1
```

Then to retrieve all posts that have the tag `a`:

```
SMEMBERS tags:a
```

Now with the retrieved ids just fetch each posts you need to display.

**PS**: HASH are more convenient than strings for storing blog posts, so instead of:

```
SET posts:1:text
```

you may want to use HMSET instead

```
HMSET posts:1 text blablabla createdAt 1385547056549
```

it will allow you to add more attributes/metadata to the post while still retrieving it easily with HGETALL or HMGET.